# C# - Image Processing How to Improve Image Threshold

Tags: c#, emgucv

I'm trying to use HSV segmentation to find the squares on the image.

The problem is that there's a HUGE shadow left by the quadcopter and I have no idea how to remove it with image processing. I cannot change the light bulbs.

[image]

Does anyone have an idea how to remove the shadow or at least decrease it?

Comment: can you go for color before you do the segmentation, assuming that the tiles/squares to detect are always colorful, and the shadow would always be sufficiently black, and invert it? you say you cannot change the light bulbs, but can you add additional lighting/camera flash, so it would become less of an umbra? or change the mechanical configuration so the camera gets a better angle?

Comment: I'm doing the Threshold HSV to segmentate the color squares from the noise and background (gray)

Comment: Do you think there's a better way to threshold the squares instead of threshold HSV?